# Is possible to declare attributes with the same name for different views?

Tags: android, android-xml

I've next problem. I create next attr.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="PublicMap">
        <attr name="public_map" format="boolean"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="SceneMap">
        <attr name="public_map" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="preview_mode" format="boolean"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

now project can not be compiled. Error is "error: Attribute "public_map" has already been defined". Is not possible to declare attributes with the same name for different views?

Comment: with this info it seems like you cant :)

Comment: This is sad =( I want create several views with the same attributes

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on one of my project and noticed that its **NOT** possible to have same *`attr`* name under different *`declare-styleable`*.

However, you may append a prefix in order to differentiate attributes with similar names.

Comment: How do I handle it if I wish to re-use an attribute

Comment: you need to use android's namespace to retrieve the existing attribute's value